# ElasticSearch - Range query on min value in array

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Given the following mapping:

```
"item": { 
    "properties": { 
        "name": { 
            "type": "string", 
            "index": "standard"  
        }, 
        "state": { 
            "type": "string", 
            "index": "not_analyzed"  
        }, 
        "important_dates": {
            "properties": {
                "city_id": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "important_date": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And given the following items in an index:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "test data 1",
    "state": "california",
    "important_dates": [
    {
        "city_id": 100,
        "important_date": "2016-01-01T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "city_id": 200,
        "important_date": "2016-05-15T00:00:00"
    }
},
{
    "_id": 2,
    "name": "test data 2",
    "state": "wisconsin",
    "important_dates": [
    {
        "city_id": 300,
        "important_date": "2016-04-10T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "city_id": 400,
        "important_date": "2016-05-20T00:00:00"
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do a range filter on important_dates, but only filter using the min date in the important_dates array? Could this also be expanded to only use the date for a specific city if a city_id was given as a parameter?

Example Queries:

If I have a range filter of 4/9/2016 to 5/17/2016 on important_dates, I only want to get back item 2 since the min date in item 1 doesn't fall within the range given.

If I have a range filter range filter of 4/9/2016 to 5/17/2016 on important_dates and pass in city_id 400, I should not get any results.

Comment: Can you update your question with the mapping you currently have? Also how many dates do you expect to have in the `important_dates` array?

Comment: @Val Question updated. There could be n number of dates in the array.